# Help with solving PDE $A\frac{\partial\omega}{\partial t} = B\frac{\partial^2\omega}{\partial \eta^2} + C$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I need help with solving a PDE of the form:
$$A\frac{\partial\omega}{\partial t} = B\frac{\partial^2\omega}{\partial \eta^2} + C$$
With $\omega = f(t,\eta)$ and A, B and C are numerical values.
It has been hinted to use seperation of independent variables or Fourier analysis(?), but I can't find an example that resembles this form due to the added C. 
Boundary conditions are $\omega=0$ for $\eta$ = 0 and 1. 
A lot of thanks in advance,
Maurits

Comment: Are $A,\,B$ both assumed to be nonzero? Find all solutions with e.g. separable $\omega-Ct/A$.

Comment: Yes, A, B and C are nonzero. Can you elaborate on what you mean with separable? Maybe link a site about this?

Comment: You can assume that $\omega=g(t)h(\eta) + C/A t$ and look how the equation results.

Comment: @korina what are g and h? I am very unfamiliar with solving PDEs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use separation of variables, we can propose a solution of the form
$$
\omega(t,\eta)=()ℎ(\eta)+\frac{}{A}
$$
where $g,h$ are two unknown functions, that we want to find out. Then we have:
$$
\frac{\partial\omega}{\partial t}='()ℎ(\eta)+\frac{}{A}
\quad
and
\quad
\frac{\partial^2\omega}{\partial \eta^2}=()ℎ''(\eta).
$$
Finally the equation results:
$$
A '()ℎ(\eta) = B ()ℎ''(\eta).
$$
We can rewrite the equation in the following form:
$$
A\frac{'()}{g(t)} = B \frac{ℎ''(\eta)}{ℎ(\eta)}.
$$
The left-hand side is independent of $\eta$ and the right-hand side is independent of $t$ so it must be equal to some constant $c$.
$$
A\frac{'()}{g(t)} = {\bf c} =B \frac{ℎ''(\eta)}{ℎ(\eta)}.
$$
Thus we have two equations:
$$
A '()-{\bf c} g(t) = 0 \quad and \quad  B ℎ''(\eta)-{\bf c} ℎ(\eta)=0
$$
which general solutions are
$$ \displaystyle
g(t)=k_1 e^{\frac{A}{ \bf c}t} \quad and \quad 
h(\eta)=k_2e^{-\sqrt{\frac{B}{\bf c}}\eta} + k_3e^{\sqrt{\frac{B}{ \bf c}}\eta}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Using the Fourier transform
$$
\hat{f}(t,\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t,\eta) \, e^{-i\xi\eta} \, d\eta.
$$
we get
$$
A\partial_t\hat{f}(t,\xi) = -B\xi^2\,\hat{f}(t,\xi) + C\,2\pi\,\delta(\xi).
$$
The homogeneous equation,
$$
A\partial_t\hat{f}(t,\xi) = -B\xi^2\,\hat{f}(t,\xi)
$$
has solutions
$$
\hat{f}_h(t,\xi) = \hat{R}(\xi)\,e^{-B\xi^2t/A},
$$
where $\hat{R}(\xi)$ is some differentiable function.

One particular solution to the inhomogeneous equation is
$$
\hat{f}_p(t, \xi) = \frac{2\pi\,C}{2B}\delta''(\xi)
$$
since $\xi^2\delta''(\xi) = 2\delta(\xi).$

Thus the complete family of solutions is given by
$$
\hat{f}(t, \xi) = \hat{R}(\xi)\,e^{-B\xi^2t/A} + \frac{2\pi\,C}{2B}\delta''(\xi).
$$

An inverse Fourier transform now gives
$$
f(t,\eta) = R*\rho(t,\eta) - \frac{C}{2B}\eta^2,
$$
where $R$ is the inverse transform of $\hat{R}$ and $\rho(t,\eta)$ is the inverse transform of $e^{-B\xi^2t/A}.$